# The request could not be mapped to any database - Error 404

Tags: oracle, tomcat, oracle-apex, apex, tomcat9

ORDS : 21.4.2, Tomcat : 9.0.63

ords is working fine on standalone mode, but on tomcat it giving error 404.

I reinstalled ords and tomcat multiple times.

- unlocked all necessary accounts
- java -jar ords.war validat comand run successully
- tried on different port
- restart tomcat

[image]

Comment: Tim has a nice post on the setup steps here https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-installation-on-tomcat#tomcat-deployment. Use that to double check you have not missed anythning

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and giving 777 permission to webapps folder under tomcat resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).